# in a css three column setup using the float:left how do I horizontally centre an image inside each column

Tags: css, css-float, center

I've taken a look through post on here but seem unable to find a solution that wants to work and I'm wondering if my float:left tags are causing the issue.

Basically I have wordpress blog I'm trying to set using nextgen gallery now for what I wish to do I need to modify way it displays a list of images.  into three sections.  Centring each image with in the column.  Now I've set this using the following code which creates the three columns fine below this its very basic but it does not work on here  I assumed I would be able to use the margin:0 auto; but this does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/locka/dcdkf/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="column-left">
<p>LEFT </p>
  <img src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtZTDwx3wVJMqWWTlCW8BDZ7fPvQVbRZpILy0NAeHIGaRxcRtR">
</div>
<div id="column-center">
    <p>MIDDLE </p>
    <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCgQRoPbKR8WpHtPZfBiPKK6NaNN3vyWqLarsKDDb0zLWd0AID"></p>
   </div>
<div id="column-right">
    <p>RIGHT </p>
   <img src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScF65ryaqzfG9gpVrld1CLJ7_5wJOpmH96FRvB4TvnkFaqyloh">
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
width: 980px;
background: silver;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#column-left {
width: 280px;
float: left;
background: red;
}

#column-center {
width: 420px;
float: left;
background: GREEN;
margin: 0 auto;

}

#column-right {
width: 280px;
float: left;
background: BLUE;
}
```

I've basically need to have 3 images in a row these may be 2 size either a landscape or portrait both same hight but different widths I need to centred each image with in it's column.  The left and right columns will be the same with as the widest image that way as landscape photo's they will always look like they are left and right aligned and if portraits appear centred in there respect columns.  Then the centre column will take up the rest of the space and this will centre all images thus giving equal border left and right. and making them tidy.

I can set up the columns following what looks to be stand way across the net how try as I might can not centre the images.

Comment: Images are inline elements by default so this is natural. I don't think you should have to wrap them in paragraph tags for them to respect the text-align?

Comment: Just had a brainwave and been able to do it on test code but not doing text-align:centre and wrapping the images in <P> paragraph markers. This however does not work on my site proper so not sure this is a fix.  If it where to work is this the best way to do it seems a little strange as it not text.

Comment: sorry peter just re posted my second comments as after testing on my site it did not work.  Are you saying I should be able to align the images using just text-align im sure I tested this one earlier and it did not work.  My site is not yet live so I cannot show what it's doing and my code from my wamp server has a lot of php and other stuff in it little to much to post but it's more or less what I've post other than the images are contain with div tags.  But I've remove all the formatting from most to test

Comment: I see. I've added an answer that I hope will clarify things and fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are by default inline elements, and will as such obey the `text-align` CSS rule of its parent. Since text-align doesn't work in your case, it must mean that your images are not inline elements anymore. Probaby there is a `img { display: block }` somewhere in your CSS.

This means that `margin: 0 auto` should do the trick. The problem is that you are applying that style on the img's container instead of on the img itself.

So, instead of

```
#column-center {
  width: 420px;
  float: left;
  background: GREEN;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

use

```
#column-center {
  width: 420px;
  float: left;
  background: GREEN;
}

#column-center img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: peter thanks for that managed to get it working with text-align:centre though I'm learning loads so it's great to understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, use `text-align: center;` to center all of a column's content. You may want to wrap the image in a div with this property if you don't want the rest of the column's content to be centered.

Comment: yep that worked once I decided to rip out all div tags and put them back one by one.  One was causing the issue though I don't know why.  That's what you get from modifying templates set-up by writer of the plug-in and and a developer who keeps changing his mind.